# How to save value into database with field type realated?

Tags: odoo

At first I have model 'account.analytic.line' with field user_id :

```
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', string='User', default=_default_user)
```

then I inherit that model and modify field user_id to related field:

```
'user_id': fields.related('employee_id', 'user_id', type="many2one", relation="res.users", string="User", required=False, default=lambda self: False),
```

but my problem is after that field user_id was removed from database (I can find it in model structure but not in database) and it cause many error relate to any models that connect to model 'account.analytic.line' through field 'user_id'.I've made many researching and effort but no luck, how I can resolve it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define `store=True`:

```py
'user_id': fields.related(
    'employee_id', 'user_id', type="many2one",
    relation="res.users", string="User", required=False,
    default=lambda self: False, store=True),
```

That will persist the value again.

Comment: exactly (y), but I need to change field to field.many2one first to create column user_id before set it as field.related with store=True